# NonLinearModelFit is overlooping throught constraints

Tags: nonlinear

I have a NonLinearModelFit in which a constraint is this formula (I have added the Print function to test)

```
ximgConst[xs_Real, xt_Real, alpha_Real, tao_Real] := 
  Print@NIntegrate[(xt - xs)*(2*Pi*freq*tao)^(1 - alpha)*
     Cos[alpha*Pi/2]/(1 + 
        2*(2*Pi*freq*tao)^(1 - alpha)*
         Sin[alpha*Pi/2] + (2*Pi*freq*tao)^(2 - 2*alpha)), {freq, 0, 
     15000}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
```

If I set the modelfit to MaxIterations->1 I am getting printed over 100 times different values per 1 iteration. Whenever I set my fit to 1000 iterations, this Integrate constraint slows down too much the fit.

Any clues?
Thanks

Adding example code: Check how fast the fit is performed when the variable "PerformIntegral" is False, but it is broken when the variable becomes True. It makes no sense to me, when PerformIntegral = False the given result matches the integral constraint. But when the PerformIntegral = True there is no way I get a fast solution.
Edit the code with the first code I gave and change the maxIterations to 1 and you'll see what I am speaking about

```
        PerformIntegral = False;
    dato = {{0, 100., 0.632135}, {1, 100., 0.145317}, {0, 300., 
         0.473025}, {1, 300., 0.23012}, {0, 600., 0.344694}, {1, 600., 
         0.234636}, {0, 1000., 0.256246}, {1, 1000., 0.211463}, {0, 2000.,
          0.166665}, {1, 2000., 0.162959}, {0, 3000., 0.12934}, {1, 3000.,
          0.133602}, {0, 4000., 0.107602}, {1, 4000., 0.113938}, {0, 
         5000., 0.0954281}, {1, 5000., 0.103238}, {0, 6000., 
         0.0847213}, {1, 6000., 0.092765}, {0, 7000., 0.0781265}, {1, 
         7000., 0.0865319}, {0, 8000., 0.0712435}, {1, 8000., 
         0.0791696}, {0, 9000., 0.0672512}, {1, 9000., 0.075166}, {0, 
         10000., 0.0628277}, {1, 10000., 0.0711438}} // 
       Rationalize[#, 0] &;
    
    omtao1 = 2*Pi*freq*tao1;
    omtao2 = 2*Pi*freq*tao2;
    ximg1 = (xt1 - xs1)*omtao1^(1 - alpha1)*
       Cos[alpha1*Pi/2]/(1 + 2*omtao1^(1 - alpha1)*Sin[alpha1*Pi/2] + 
          omtao1^(2 - 2*alpha1));
    ximg2 = (xt2 - xs2)*omtao2^(1 - alpha2)*
       Cos[alpha2*Pi/2]/(1 + 2*omtao2^(1 - alpha2)*Sin[alpha2*Pi/2] + 
          omtao2^(2 - 2*alpha2));
    ximg = ximg1 + ximg2;
    xreal1 = xs1 + (xt1 - 
          xs1)*(1 + omtao1^(1 - alpha1)*Sin[alpha1*Pi/2])/(1 + 
           2*omtao1^(1 - alpha1)*Sin[alpha1*Pi/2] + omtao1^(2 - 2*alpha1));
    xreal2 = xs2 + (xt2 - 
          xs2)*(1 + omtao2^(1 - alpha2)*Sin[alpha2*Pi/2])/(1 + 
           2*omtao2^(1 - alpha2)*Sin[alpha2*Pi/2] + omtao2^(2 - 2*alpha2));
    xreal = xreal1 + xreal2;
    cole = ximg/xreal*xrealExp;
    
    ximgConst[xs_?NumericQ, xt_?NumericQ, alpha_?NumericQ, 
       tao_?NumericQ] := 
      NIntegrate[
       Rationalize[(xt - xs)*(2*Pi*freq*tao)^(1 - alpha)*
         Cos[alpha*Pi/2]/(1 + 
            2*(2*Pi*freq*tao)^(1 - alpha)*
             Sin[alpha*Pi/2] + (2*Pi*freq*tao)^(2 - 2*alpha)), 0], {freq, 
        0, 15000}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
    xsinf1 = 0;
    inixs1 = 0;
    limxs1 = 14/10;
    limxt1 = 2;
    inixt1 = 6/10;
    inialpha1 = 2/10;
    initao1 = 2/100;
    xsinf2 = 0;
    inixs2 = inixs1;
    limxs2 = limxs1;
    limxt2 = limxt1;
    inixt2 = inixt1;
    inialpha2 = inialpha1;
    initao2 = initao1;
    actualPropProces = 1;
    RealPropProces = 
      1/(1 + ximgConst[xs2, xt2, alpha2, tao2]/
          ximgConst[xs1, xt1, alpha1, tao1]);
    model = {(1 - set)*xreal + 
         set*ximg, {xsinf1 < xs1 < (limxs1 + 1/10)*5/2, 
         xs1 < xt1 < limxt1*5/2, 
         0 < alpha1 < Min[1, inialpha1*5], 0 < tao1 < Min[1, initao1*5], xt1 < xt2, xsinf2 < xs2 < (limxs2 + 1/10)*5/2, xs2 < xt2 < limxt2*5/2, 
         0 < alpha2 < Min[1, inialpha2*5], 0 < tao2 < Min[1, initao2*5], 
         If[PerformIntegral, RealPropProces < actualPropProces*11/10, 
          True]}} // Flatten;
    
    fit = NonlinearModelFit[Rationalize[dato, 0], Rationalize[model, 0], 
       Rationalize[{{xs1, inixs1}, {xt1, inixt1}, {alpha1, 
          inialpha1}, {tao1, initao1}, {xs2, inixs2}, {xt2, 
          inixt2}, {alpha2, inialpha2}, {tao2, initao2}}, 0], {set, freq},
        MaxIterations -> 10000, WorkingPrecision -> 22];
    
    fit[[1, 2]]
"Prop: " <> ToString[RealPropProces /. fit[[1, 2]]]
    Show[Plot[Evaluate[fit[#, freq] & /@ {0, 1}], {freq, 100, 10000}, 
      PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[{Set0, Set1}, {0.5, 0.5}]], 
     ListPlot[Map[Rest, GatherBy[dato, First], {2}]], 
     PlotRange -> {0, Max[dato[[All, 3]]]}]
```

Comment: Please include a minimal working (or non-working) example.  Your question is about `NonlinearModelFit` and yet your current example doesn't contain `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Use `ximgConst[xs_?NumericQ, xt_?NumericQ, alpha_?NumericQ, tao_?NumericQ]:= ...`then an argument can also be an integer, rational, or numeric constant (e.g., `E`, `Pi`)

Comment: @JimB done, I hope that helps. I have simplified the code so it causes less confussion
 BobHanlon that doesn't help :( but thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
PerformIntegral = True;
```

Your [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) uses `WorkingPrecision -> 22`. You cannot achieve greater than machine precision if you introduce machine precision values. [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) your `dato`

```
dato = {{0, 100., 0.632135}, {1, 100., 0.145317}, {0, 300., 0.473025}, {1, 
     300., 0.23012}, {0, 600., 0.344694}, {1, 600., 0.234636}, {0, 1000., 
     0.256246}, {1, 1000., 0.211463}, {0, 2000., 0.166665}, {1, 2000., 
     0.162959}, {0, 3000., 0.12934}, {1, 3000., 0.133602}, {0, 4000., 
     0.107602}, {1, 4000., 0.113938}, {0, 5000., 0.0954281}, {1, 5000., 
     0.103238}, {0, 6000., 0.0847213}, {1, 6000., 0.092765}, {0, 7000., 
     0.0781265}, {1, 7000., 0.0865319}, {0, 8000., 0.0712435}, {1, 8000., 
     0.0791696}, {0, 9000., 0.0672512}, {1, 9000., 0.075166}, {0, 10000., 
     0.0628277}, {1, 10000., 0.0711438}} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

omtao1 = 2*Pi*freq*tao1;
omtao2 = 2*Pi*freq*tao2;
ximg1 = (xt1 - xs1)*omtao1^(1 - alpha1)*
   Cos[alpha1*Pi/2]/(1 + 2*omtao1^(1 - alpha1)*Sin[alpha1*Pi/2] + 
      omtao1^(2 - 2*alpha1));
ximg2 = (xt2 - xs2)*omtao2^(1 - alpha2)*
   Cos[alpha2*Pi/2]/(1 + 2*omtao2^(1 - alpha2)*Sin[alpha2*Pi/2] + 
      omtao2^(2 - 2*alpha2));
ximg = ximg1 + ximg2;
xreal1 = xs1 + (xt1 - 
      xs1)*(1 + omtao1^(1 - alpha1)*Sin[alpha1*Pi/2])/(1 + 
       2*omtao1^(1 - alpha1)*Sin[alpha1*Pi/2] + omtao1^(2 - 2*alpha1));
xreal2 = xs2 + (xt2 - 
      xs2)*(1 + omtao2^(1 - alpha2)*Sin[alpha2*Pi/2])/(1 + 
       2*omtao2^(1 - alpha2)*Sin[alpha2*Pi/2] + omtao2^(2 - 2*alpha2));
xreal = xreal1 + xreal2;
cole = ximg/xreal*xrealExp;

ximgConst[xs_?NumericQ, xt_?NumericQ, alpha_?NumericQ, tao_?NumericQ] :=
  
  NIntegrate[
   (xt - xs)*(2*Pi*freq*tao)^(1 - alpha)*
    Cos[alpha*Pi/2]/(1 + 
       2*(2*Pi*freq*tao)^(1 - alpha)*
        Sin[alpha*Pi/2] + (2*Pi*freq*tao)^(2 - 2*alpha)), {freq, 0, 15000}, 
   Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
```

Your `NonlinearModelFit` uses `WorkingPrecision -> 22`. You cannot achieve greater than machine precision if you introduce machine precision values. `Rationalize` or use exact values for your parameters.

```
xsinf1 = 0;
inixs1 = 0;
limxs1 = 14/10;
limxt1 = 2;
inixt1 = 6/10;
inialpha1 = 2/10;
initao1 = 2/100;
xsinf2 = 0;
inixs2 = inixs1;
limxs2 = limxs1;
limxt2 = limxt1;
inixt2 = inixt1;
inialpha2 = inialpha1;
initao2 = initao1;
actualPropProces = 1;
RealPropProces = 
  1/(1 + ximgConst[xs2, xt2, alpha2, tao2]/ximgConst[xs1, xt1, alpha1, tao1]);
```

[`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) is not a mathematical function, your use implies that you intend it to function as [`Max`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html) so use `Max`

```
model = {(1 - set)*xreal + set*ximg, {xsinf1 < xs1 < (limxs1 + 1/10)*5/2, 
     xs1 < xt1 < limxt1*5/2, 0 < alpha1 < Max[1, inialpha1*5], 
     0 < tao1 < Max[1, initao1*5], xt1 < xt2, 
     xsinf2 < xs2 < (limxs2 + 1/10)*5/2, xs2 < xt2 < limxt2*5/2, 
     0 < alpha2 < Max[1, inialpha2*5], 0 < tao2 < Max[1, initao2*5], 
     If[PerformIntegral, RealPropProces < actualPropProces*11/10, True]}} // 
   Flatten;

fit = NonlinearModelFit[dato, 
   model, {{xs1, inixs1}, {xt1, inixt1}, {alpha1, inialpha1}, {tao1, 
     initao1}, {xs2, inixs2}, {xt2, inixt2}, {alpha2, inialpha2}, {tao2, 
     initao2}}, {set, freq}, MaxIterations -> 10000, WorkingPrecision -> 22];
```

`fit` takes arguments (`[ ]`) not part specifications (`[[ ]]`)

```
fit[1, 2]

(* 0.01223871754878109269063 *)
```

`fit[1, 2]`is a number not a [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) so the next statement makes no sense.

```
(* "Prop: "<>ToString[RealPropProces/.fit[1,2]] *)

Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[fit[#, freq] & /@ {0, 1}], {freq, 100, 10000},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{Set0, Set1}, {0.5, 0.5}]],
 ListPlot[Map[Rest, GatherBy[dato, First], {2}]],
 PlotRange -> MinMax[dato[[All, 3]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: The Rationalize function actually solves some warning messages, thank you!. Instead of using Max y decided to use Rescale[initao2*5, {0, 1}], that works quite better. Your code is quick, but that's due to the Max function on tao. Max[1,0.1] would choose 1, that value exceeds the limit I wanted to use (0.1). Therefore, I have updated my code on my first comment with your changes. When the variable PerformIntegral = False it works as expected, but when it becomes True, the calculation is slowed down by a loooooot. But actually, your comment helped me at atleast 50% of my issues

Comment: By the way, I have learned somestuff about how to write better code on mathematica. I have seen some tricks on your code, my mind is blown